# Join between ManyToMany properties at Doctrine2 entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, symfony-2.6

I have this tables relationship:

[image]

This is how my entities for `messages` and `emails` looks like (I've just added the important info):

```
class Message
{
    /**
     * @var Brand
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brand")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brands_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $brand;

    ...

}


class Email
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Message", inversedBy="messageXrefMail", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="emails_messages_xref",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="emails_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="messages_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $emailsMessageXref;

    ...
}
```

I need to get the `brands` related to `email` but I don't know how to do it in this scenario. The are a few tables included on the main query and I got this:

```
public function findEmailValues($eid)
{
    $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('e.id', 'r.id')
        ->from('PDOneBundle:Email', 'e')
        ->leftJoin('PDOneBundle:Representative', 'r', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'e.rep = r.id')
        ->leftJoin('PDOneBundle:Territory', 't', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'r.territory = t.id')
        ->leftJoin('PDOneBundle:Target', 'tg', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 't.id = tg.territory')
        ->where('e.id = :eid')
        ->setParameter('eid', $eid);

    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
}
```

But I don't know where to go from there. Can I get some help building the DQL?

Comment: How's the relationship between brand and email look?

Comment: @Richard there is not relation between those two

Comment: You're asking how to get the brands related to email though, do you mean via the email -> messages -> brands relationship?

Comment: @Richard exactly that is what I am asking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
    $qb->select('e.id', 'r.id', 'br')
        ->from('PDOneBundle:Email', 'e')
        ->leftJoin('PDOneBundle:Representative', 'r', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'e.rep = r.id')
        ->leftJoin('PDOneBundle:Territory', 't', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'r.territory = t.id')
        ->leftJoin('PDOneBundle:Target', 'tg', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 't.id = tg.territory')
        ->leftJoin('e.emailsMessageXref', 'me') // many to many on email -> messages
        ->leftJoin('me.brand', 'br') // many to one on message -> brand
        ->where('e.id = :eid')
        ->setParameter('eid', $eid);
```

Comment: Note that it would probably be better to rename the $emailsMessageXref property in Email to $messages - it's a lot clearer to read.

Comment: Also, if your relations are set up right you should not need the \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH part. E.g. ->leftJoin('PDOneBundle:Representative', 'r', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'e.rep = r.id') can be re-written as ->leftJoin('e.representative', 'r')